# Why is there no alert when the condition is triggered?

Tags: javascript

I implemented validation for empty input field in the handlers:

```
if(inputsAdd[0] === "" || inputsAdd[1] === "" || inputsAdd[2] === ""){
    alert ("fill all fields");}
```

In the handler: `buttDelete.addEventListener` the same way, but for some reason, checking for the emptiness of the form does not work. Help fix

```js
const formAdd = document.forms[0];
const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (inputsAdd[0] === "" || inputsAdd[1] === "" || inputsAdd[2] === "") {
        alert("fill all fields");
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        shop.addProduct(new Product(inputsAdd[0].value, parseInt(inputsAdd[2].value),
            parseInt(inputsAdd[1].value)));
        shop.show();
        inputsAdd[0].value = "";
        inputsAdd[1].value = "";
        inputsAdd[2].value = "";
    }
}, false);
// delete product by name after click
const formDelete = document.forms[1];
const nameDelete = formDelete.elements[0];
const buttDelete = formDelete.elements[1];
buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (nameDelete === "") {
        alert("write a name of product what you want to delete");
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        shop.deleteProductByName(nameDelete.value);
        shop.show();
        nameDelete.value = "";
    }

}, false);
let shop = new Shop();
```

```html
        <form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </form>    
<form id="delete-form">
        <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
        <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `inputsAdd[0]` be the element, so it'd be an object and never equal to a empty string? So do what you're doing in the code below `inputsAdd[0].value === ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inputsAdd[0], inputsAdd[1] ,inputsAdd[2]`  are objects.Using `.value` on these objects you can get the value for comparison

**Change this**

```
if (inputsAdd[0] === "" || inputsAdd[1] === "" || inputsAdd[2] === ""){
            alert("fill all fields");
        }
```

**to**

```
if (inputsAdd[0].value === "" || inputsAdd[1].value === "" || inputsAdd[2].value === "") {
        alert("fill all fields");
    }
```

**Also need to change `nameDelete` to `nameDelete.value`**

```js
const formAdd = document.forms[0];
const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (inputsAdd[0].value === "" || inputsAdd[1].value === "" || inputsAdd[2].value === "") {
        alert("fill all fields");
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        shop.addProduct(new Product(inputsAdd[0].value, parseInt(inputsAdd[2].value),
            parseInt(inputsAdd[1].value)));
        shop.show();
        inputsAdd[0].value = "";
        inputsAdd[1].value = "";
        inputsAdd[2].value = "";
    }
}, false);
// delete product by name after click
const formDelete = document.forms[1];
const nameDelete = formDelete.elements[0];
const buttDelete = formDelete.elements[1];
buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (nameDelete.value === "") {
        alert("write a name of product what you want to delete");
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        shop.deleteProductByName(nameDelete.value);
        shop.show();
        nameDelete.value = "";
    }

}, false);
```

```html
<form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </form>    
<form id="delete-form">
        <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
        <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are of the element's themselves and not the values, simply add `.value` as you're doing when you set them as empty strings and it should work.

Do the same for the `nameDelete` check

```js
const formAdd = document.forms[0];
const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (inputsAdd[0].value === "" || inputsAdd[1].value === "" || inputsAdd[2].value === "") {
    alert("fill all fields");
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputsAdd[0].value = "";
    inputsAdd[1].value = "";
    inputsAdd[2].value = "";
  }
}, false);
// delete product by name after click
const formDelete = document.forms[1];
const nameDelete = formDelete.elements[0];
const buttDelete = formDelete.elements[1];
buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (nameDelete.value === "") {
    alert("write a name of product what you want to delete");
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    nameDelete.value = "";
  }

}, false);
```

```html
<form id="addForm">
  <label for="name">Name of product</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" class="input-product">
  <label for="price">Price of product</label>
  <input type="text" id="price" class="input-product">
  <label for="count">Count of product</label>
  <input type="text" id="count" class="input-product">
  <button id="add">Add</button>
</form>
<form id="delete-form">
  <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
  <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
</form>
```

I've removed the `Shop` so the code runs here

Answer (score 0):

It may help to set your form's initial values to empty strings in the HTML.

```
<input ... value="">
```

I'm always wary to ensure initial values are predictable. For example, what if a browser or framework considers the initial values to be `undefined`?